# python-3 extract json from gz and encode utf-8

Tags: python, json, utf-8, gzip

I get 60 gz files on a daily basis and these files have a json document each. After I extract .gz file I get a json file with utf-8-bom encoding which causes problem in loading loading json later on. I have tried below code which for some reason works on some of my .gz files and doesn't work on some.

```
with gzip.open(source_filepath, 'rb') as s_file, \
        open(dest_filepath, 'wb') as d_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(s_file, d_file, block_size)
    s = open(dest_filepath, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
    open(dest_filepath, mode='w', encoding='utf-8').write(s)
    print('File unzipped.')
```

I have tried using chardet to check the encoding of the files which don't convert to 'utf-8' the result there is 'utf-8-sig' so it should work but I can't seem to figure out why is not working.

I have the below code to load json using ijson

```
def load_json3(filepath):
    print('Extracting values from JSON...')
    my_oids = []
    my_edition = []
    my_action = []
    pdict = {}
    #global dfObj
    with open(filepath, 'r') as input_file:
        parser = ijson.parse(input_file, multiple_values=True)
        for prefix, event, value in parser:
            #print('prefix={}, event={}, value={}'.format(prefix, event, value))
            if prefix == 'OID':
                my_oids.append(value)
                pdict['ID'] = [value]
            elif prefix == 'edition':
                my_edition.append(value)
                pdict['edition'] = [value]
            elif prefix == 'action':
                my_action.append(value)
                pdict['action'] = [value]
```

json file looks like below:

{"ID":"2294.89748","edition":1,"timeStamp":"2020-03-17T08:46:56.701","transactionID":195787618595,"action":"CREATED","acct_no":"8XXX6780XXXX","cust_no":5XXX5,"status":"A","myGlobal":"[3008.1]"}

{"ID":"2294.74400","edition":1,"timeStamp":"2020-03-17T11:10:23.503","transactionID":195795719559,"action":"UPDATED","status":"D"}

and the error message I get is this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

runtime_1   |   File "", line 329, in

runtime_1   |     recon1()

runtime_1   |   File "", line 122, in recon1

runtime_1   |     df = load_json3(filepath)  # pd.read_json(filepath, lines=True)  # json dataframe

runtime_1   |   File "", line 270, in load_json3

runtime_1   |     for prefix, event, value in parser:

runtime_1   | ijson.common.IncompleteJSONError: lexical error: invalid char in json text.

runtime_1   |                                             ?{"ID":"2294.89740","edition

runtime_1   |             (right here) ------^

This is a ijson error message. If I try to load the same file with the standard 'json.loads' I get this error message "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Comment: I managed to make it work by skipping first 3 bytes in the files. So it works for 57 out of 60 files. For 3 files it adds a character in one of the lines. Visually that character says 'NUL' in notpad++ with a red background. The script fails with error "ijson.common.IncompleteJSONError: lexical error: invalid char in json text"